# Late 80’s early 90’s children’s animated movie with a crochet or patchwork owl?

Tags: story-identification, animation

Hello all I read the section on how to ask a question and thusly here is all I can give.

This was a full length animated children’s movie along the same time as Little Nemo’s.

Adventures in Dreamland and Fern Gully came out. I remember watching it one night after my parents had rented it for me at Blockbuster. The only scene I can remember (and that has haunted me for years) is this multi colored (I am seeing in my head mostly orange, yellow, browns and black colors) patchwork or knitted owl running, the scene is tense and dark possibly night time
and I feel like it is during the “end battle” scene of the movie. The owl is running either from something/one to protect something/one or towards someone to give the person an object of dire importance. Something snags a loose thread or string on the owl and from the feet up the creature begins to unravel until you see him come to the end of the string that makes him and he is no more.

This scene has stayed with me because not only do I not know what it was, but I cannot remember whether the owl truly sacrificed himself as it seems or if he was brought back to life in the end.

I know the scene definitely had you believe and feel at the time that the owl gave his life willingly and would have been able to stop and put himself together if he had the time but knowing he would completely unravel chose to do so to help the greater cause.

Anyway any help would be great the scene has haunted me for years, people think I am crazy, but I know I saw this and want to know what happened to the owl!

Comment: This is not much help, I know, but I have vague memories of seeing film posters in the mid-nineties (a little later than you are thinking of) for a movie that featured really cute animated knitted or soft toys as characters. It was obviously aimed at the same market as the *Toy Story* movies.

Comment: +1 for a good question. I'd give another +1 for reading how to ask if I could. :)

Comment: I wasn't around during then, but for whatever weird reason, this reminds me of something, but I don't know what.

Comment: @DarthVader I'm getting that same feeling, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: @JoshHunt I'm assuming this is in the US, and that the movie was 2D animated. Are these correct assumptions?

Comment: Were all the character knit/patchwork? What was the animation style (stop-motion/claymation/cartoon/disney-like/computer-gen)? What language was the film?

Comment: Do you remember another movie from the time, maybe Forrest Gump?

Comment: Was it definitely an owl? The end of Aladdin has the Magic Carpet unraveling while trying to get the magic lamp. Dark, tense scene, animated, same time frame.

Comment: I know it's not it but for some reason your description reminded me of Bagpuss.

Answer (score 1):

There was an *eye-patched* (not patch worked) barn owl in **Once Upon a Forest** that had some pretty spooky scenes, he started out as a villain but may have turned good by the end, I'm not sure... I can't remember the exact plot but this was made in the 90's and if Fern Gully is your reference point then this one had a similar style too.

[image: Barn Owl]

Comment: I don't think this is it. OP specifically describes the owl unraveling. And I am pretty sure the owl in Once Upon a Forest keeps going after the children till they escape. Props for remembering 6-year-old me's favorite movie, though!

Comment: Thank you all for the thoughts and again I realize it isn’t much to go on but none of those are the film I am thinking of as I haven’t seen them but I hope someone can illuminate this for me! I will add details if I remember any but I’ve been puzzling this for years so have about all the details I am likely to remember.

Comment: Well all it has been a while and still no answers so I feel I am either crazy or the answer is just lost to time...... or the mandala effect!?!

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this and guess that your childhood memory has conflated a couple of different scenes/ideas from [The Secret of NIMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_of_NIMH).

This movie came out in 1982, so a little earlier than the Ferngully era (1992) you describe, but certainly would have been popular at the time, and active on Blockbuster shelves in that period/genre. Nobody actually unravels but the themes/impressions struck me as similar to your question and I was hoping it might ring a bell.

Owl:

There's a big scary owl who's kind of decrepit, and rendered in dark browns and yellows:

[image]

Here's the whole scene:

Unraveling/string:

There's a very scary scene where the protagonist meets a crow who's all tangled up in yarn/string and they have a very near escape from a vicious farm cat.

[image]

Here's the whole scene: